# Android: ListView ..Convert between Click mode and Multiple Select Mode ( Like: Messaging App )

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-listview, android-adapter

The ListView will display Contacts.

options:

1-Click Mode.
If the user clicks on an item (TextView is displayed only), the app will start an new activity(contact profile).

2-Select Mode.
If the user chooses Add to contacts from menu or actionbar item, the Listview will change to Select mode (Textview + Checkbox for every item).

1-How to hide and show the checkbox ?

2-How to respond to the events ?

The Code:

The layout of the Activity:

```
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:background="@drawable/screen_background"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <SearchView
    android:id="@+id/search_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textCapWords"
    android:iconifiedByDefault="false" >
  </SearchView>
   <View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="10dp"
    android:background="#000000" />
   <ListView
    android:id="@+id/listview_Menu"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice" >
   </ListView>

  </LinearLayout>
```

The List View item Layout:

```
  <LinearLayout
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
   android:orientation="horizontal">

    <CheckBox
     android:id="@+id/listview_checkbox_item"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

   <TextView
    android:id="@+id/listview_textview_item"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="#fefefe"
    android:textSize="25sp" >
   </TextView>

  </LinearLayout>
```

The ActivityClass

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.list_view_screen);

    String[] contacts = {"aaaa aaa", "bbbb bbbb" ,"ccccccc" ,"ddddd dddd" ,"ffffff ffffff"};

    final ArrayAdapter<String> adapt = 
     new ArrayAdapter<String>( this, R.layout.list_view_item,   
                              R.id.listview_textview_item,items);


    ListView menuList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview_Menu);
      menuList.setAdapter(adapt);

       menuList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View itemClicked,
                int position, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            startActivity(new Intent(this,
                    ContactProfile.class));

        }

    });

    menuList.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener(){

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int arg2, long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }


    });

 }
```

Answer (score 3):

I think I found the Answer.

Firstly:

In the list_view_item Layout. For the

TextView android:textIsSelectable="false"
CheckBox android:visibility="invisible"

to Allow the **click mode**. (setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() will work)

Secondly:

Show or Hide all the checkboxes.

```
        ListView menuList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview_Menu);
        for(int i=0; i < menuList.getChildCount(); i++){
            LinearLayout itemLayout = (LinearLayout)menuList.getChildAt(i);
            CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)itemLayout.findViewById(R.id.listview_checkbox_item);
           cb.setVisibility((cb.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE)? View.INVISIBLE :  View.VISIBLE);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you set up the list correctly, you want to put `android:visibility="invisible"` in the checkbox definition and then use `listview_checkbox_item.setVisibility()` in your action bar button callback function to toggle the visiblity.

Comment: How to catch the events ?
I can develop the click mode alone. (No Checkbox in the Layout from the beginning).
If I added Checkbox, OnClickItem doesn't work.

Comment: 1 checkbox becomes visible only !

Comment: Try resetting your adapterview after you set the visibility of the checkboxes. Then, in your onitemclick, you can find the state of the button by getting listview_checkbox_item.isChecked().

Comment: public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
  
case R.id.delete_contacts:
   CheckBox checkbox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.listview_checkbox_item);
   checkbox.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
   return true;

Comment: The check box of the first item only become visible.

Comment: Did you try refreshing the listview after you set the visibility of the checkboxes? Not sure why that would happen. *If my answer was at all helpful, please upvote :)

Comment: Just one checkbox that appear and disappear!
Thanks for you help

Comment: I found the answer.

ListView menuList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview_Menu);   
for(int i=0; i < menuList.getChildCount(); i++){
LinearLayout itemLayout = (LinearLayout)menuList.getChildAt(i);       CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)itemLayout.findViewById(R.id.listview_checkbox_item);  cb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}

Comment: ahh, you had to iterate over the children. I was just about to suggest that. Dont forget to upvote :P

Comment: Thank you very very much for your help.
You showed me the beginning of the road :)

Comment: I have another question, Please ?
The real app will get the data from Internet. 
(XML key/value) name&ID for every Contact
When the app receives it, What is the best practice?
1-Use ArrayAdapter or Create custom adapter

Comment: Sorry Prince, I cant help you with that...I've only ever used the array adapter. Good luck though!

Comment: @Prince: Its in your project requirement and the number of data comming from the server. If there are more complex data (like empName, empDate, empID, empJoining... etc) comming from the server then it is best practice to make the Custom Adapter and store that data in to Object class and make Array Adapter of that class. Or if the data are in simple like just string then it is good to store it in to String ArrayList. Hope you got the point.